# Fluent NHibernate filter child collection with Linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to retrieve a root aggregate and its children, applying a date filter on child collection.

```
CREATE TABLE Shop
(
    Id int
)

CREATE TABLE Order
(
    ShopId int,
    OrderDate datetime
)
```

Naturally, child object doesn't have a ShopId property to avoid bi-directional reference:

```
class Shop
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<Order> { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

And FNHB mappings looks like this:

```
public ShopMap()
{
    this.Table("SHOP");
    this.Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
    this.HasMany(x => x.Orders).Table("ORDER").KeyColumn("SHOP_ID");
}

public OrderMap()
{
    this.Table("ORDER");
    this.Map(x => x.OrderDate);
}
```

**I'm trying to retrieve a given Shop with its Orders placed between certain dates**, given parameters `shopId, fromDate, toDate`, I've tried this but it throws exception:

```
Session.Query<Shop>().Where(shop => shop.Id == shopId)
.FetchMany(
    shop => shop.Orders.Where(
        order => order .OrderDate >= fromDate && order.OrderDate <= toDate));
```

Can this be achieved without a use of Magic Strings (NHb criteria, HQL etc.), preferebly with a simple Linq query?

Comment: It can be done with QueryOver if that's acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the date conditions to appear on the ON clause of the join, while the check for the shopId should be on the WHERE clause. Try this:

```
Shop shopAlias = null;
Order orderAlias = null;

ICriterion dateCriterion = Restrictions.Where<Order>
    (o => o.OrderDate >= fromDate && o.OrderDate <= toDate);

var query =
    QueryOver.Of(() => shopAlias).Left.JoinAlias(
    () => shopAlias.Orders, () => orderAlias, dateCriterion).Where
    (s => s.Id == shopId);
var result = query.GetExecutableQueryOver(Session).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure it out using Query but can do it using QueryOver:

```
Shop shopAlias = null;
var existing = QueryOver.Of<Order>()
                        .Where(x => x.OrderDate >= fromDate)
                        .And(x => x.OrderDate <= toDate)
                        .And(x => x.Shop.Id == shopAlias.Id)
                        .Select(x => x.Shop);

result = Session.QueryOver<Shop>(() => shopAlias)
                .Fetch(x => x.Orders).Eager
                .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(existing)
                .List();
```

Something like that should work.

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/01/revisiting-exists-in-nhibernate-3-0-and-queryover/

Comment: thanks, however this won't work for me as the Order object has no Shop property.

Comment: Does it have a ShopId? If you're mapping one direction why aren't you mapping the other, for the purpose of not assigning the Id directly, you have to assign the shop instance.

Comment: what are you doing in the 2nd query? it looks like it's looking for all shops except for those I actually need... _I'm trying to retrieve a given Shop with its Orders placed between certain dates_